# Bootstrap - navbar-toggle: How To Change its Function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap V3.3.6.  When my break point is 768px, it shows the menu icon `navbar-toggle`.  Clicking on this icon, there is a drop down menu (slide down) from `nav navbar-nav`.

Instead of sliding down, I'd like to change to slide out from the side (left or right)

I am looking the location of jQuery code, which make the drop down menu and then change it to slide out from the side (I have tried but didn't see it anywhere).  Or can I overwrite this jQuery code?

Please give a hand.

Thanks

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
        ........
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess this using telepathy? Please add some relevant code the the question

Comment: Pretty sure all the JS code does is change a class name or something like that – the rest is taken care of by CSS (as it should be.)

Comment: Thank you, CBroe.  I think so, too.  But a way to show up the menu is controlled by Jquery and don't know where is the Jquery code located.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the only thing manipulated within the Javascript file is the class names.  The rest is taken care of by CSS.

There is a popular fork of Bootstrap called Jasny that incorporates the left or right slide in menu that you're after.  Take a look [here](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#offcanvas).